# I am getting Error while running the Angular application

Tags: angular

I am getting this error after Running ng serve , when I  run the Application second time , error is vanished and project is 100 % loaded

```
ERROR in multi ./src/styles.css ../node_module/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '/Users/user/Projects/A4/node_module/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css' in '/Users/user/Projects/A4/demo'
ERROR in error TS1149: File name '/Users/user/Projects/A4/demo/src/modles/latestprices.ts' differs from already included file name '/Users/user/Projects/A4/demo/src/modles/Latestprices.ts' only in casing.
error TS1149: File name '/Users/user/Projects/A4/demo/src/modles/venuDate.ts' differs from already included file name '/Users/user/Projects/A4/demo/src/modles/VenuDate.ts' only in casing.
```

Comment: what do you mean with 'after i save page', what page?

Comment: You might be installing bootstrap while using it and before it was installed.

Comment: maybe it helps if you empty your browser history/cache. Does the same problem occur with multiple browsers?